# Delphi Undeclared identifier

Tags: delphi

I am trying to fix an old Delphi software. But i haven't used Delphi very long time. when i try to run the software :

```
 [Fatal Error] CHAINU.PAS(10): File not found: 'TCustAbs.dcu'
```

In main POHook.dpr file

```
 Uses Classes, Dialogs, Forms, IniFiles, SysUtils, Windows, CustAbsU,
 Menus, EntMenuU, TCustAbs;
```

There is a TCUSTABS.PAS file inside the folder called BaseFile, Basefile Folder and POHOOK.dpr are in the same folder.

[Fatal Error] CHAINU.PAS(10): File not found: 'TCustAbs.dcu' 
Where is this .dcu file?

Comment: Use the Project->Add to Project menu option to locate the TCustAbs.pas file, so the project knows where to fnd that file. After that, it will generate the .TCustAbs.dcu when the project is compiled.

Comment: If you haven't used Delphi for a very long time, perhaps you should consider some revision, rather than expecting immediate success. My advice is to spend some time re-learning the tools necessary to do the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There is a TCUSTABS.PAS file inside the folder called BaseFile, Basefile Folder and POHOOK.dpr are in the same folder.

The compiler isn't going to automagically search folders for you unless you specifically add the folder to the project's search path, which is generally a bad idea unless it's a third party library.  (Which it doesn't appear to be, if it's in the same folder as your DPR.)  What would be better is to add the TCUSTABS.PAS file to the project itself.  Then the compiler will have no trouble finding it.

Comment: Why would adding the BaseFile subdirectory to the search path generally be a bad idea?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Because it's implicit, and the more implicit state in the compiler, the greater the chances of something going wrong.  (For example, having two units with the same name in two different search path folders, and picking up the wrong one.)  Being explicit is always better when it's feasible.